# What SAAJ package is used by WebLogic

Tags: soap, weblogic, weblogic11g, saaj

I have had many problems because there are different SAAJ packages with SOAP classes:

- `com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/soap/`    in rt.jar
- `com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/`               in saaj-impl.jar

When WebLogic uses classes from `com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/soap/` and an application is created using classes from `com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/`, it throws exceptions like these when the app is deployed:

`com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings != com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings`

or

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/soap/SAAJMetaFactoryImpl`

My solution was create a weblogic.xml descriptor with saaj reference and including saaj-impl.jar into the war.
Question is: **Can I know what SAAJ package is used in WebLogic Server?**

Answer (score 1):

If you use weblogic 10.3.3(or i think even any other version) , the SAAJ implementation used by is of the JDK runtime installed since the web server initializes the CLASSPATH to the JDK `jars` first. So you need to override it with your jar file so it can find your desired implementation first.
The only solution with weblogic that worked for me was to set `PRE_CLASSPATH` in weblogic `setDomainEnv.cmd` file like this,

```
          set PRE_CLASSPATH=%DOMAIN_HOME%\lib\endorsed\saaj-impl-1.3.18.jar
```

whereby `DOMAIN_HOME` represents Weblogic domain, but it can be any other absolute path as well to point the jar. A bit about the issue is also described [Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-3307)